# Why is division on Z not a poset?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

Why is division on natural number a poset but division on Z is not a poset? Is is because we get ordered pair such as (-1,1) and (1,-1) which is not antisymmetric?

Comment: Yep. Technically, its a [proset](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/preorder). Of course, you can always identify points $x$ and $y$ in a proset satisfying $x \lesssim y$ and $y \lesssim x$ in order to obtain a poset. However, if you do this for the divisibility relation in a ring like $\mathbb{Z}$, the resulting poset won't interact sensibly with addition. So, we usually don't bother.

Comment: @user18921: Please don't use the term proset. It's a bad term. preorder or quasi order are much much better terms.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, true, and I don't mind the expression "quasiordered set," so I think I'll use this from now on. "Pre-ordered set" just sounds too much like a (possibly empty) pizza that I ordered prior to pickup.

Comment: @AsafKaragila while I agree that poset is not the best of terms (it should have been 'ordered set'), it is the accepted terminology in too many areas. It's too late to change it now (without a time-machine that is).

Comment: @Ittay: And that's exactly why I said that **proset** is a bad term for a preordered set. Because it is so easy to confuse it with poset. :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila oh my... point (oh so) well made :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to make sure the notation is clear. If you declare $x\le y$ when $x$ divides $y$, then this defines a partial order on $\mathbb N$ but not on $\mathbb Z$. I think that this is what you are saying. And the reason is indeed that on $\mathbb Z$ this relation is not anti-symmetric, as for instance it is the case that $1\le -1$ and $-1\le 1$.